# $n$-partite graph formed by $\{0,1,2, \dots, n-1\}^k$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

There are a lot of questions about how a graph $Q_k$ and it is also known as the k-cube and it is bipartite. Where, a $Q_k$ whose vertices are labeled by strings of length $k$ over $\{0, 1\}$. There is an edge between to vertices if the strings that label them differ in exactly one place.

Now, what would change if this graph, $Q_k$ and it was formed by $n$-ary strings of length $k$. And, there is an edge between to vertices if the strings that label them differ in exactly one place. How would such a graph be $n$-partite?

Comment: If you're thinking about this graph $Q_k$ a lot, it may be useful to note that $Q_k$ is the $k$-term product of complete graphs $K_3\times K_3 \times, \dots, \times K_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following colouring proves that $3$ colours are sufficient (i.e. that such a graph is tripartite): Given a string $s \in \{0, 1, 2 \}^k$ we denote by $f(s)$ the sum of the digits of $s$. We define our colouring to be the function $C$ which maps $s$ to the sum of its digits modulo $3$, i.e. $C : s \rightarrow \mathcal{R}_3(f(s))$.

Consider any two adjacent strings $s$ and $s'$. They differ in exactly one position. Without loss of generality we have $f(s) < f(s') < f(s) + 3$. Hence $\mathcal{R}_3(f(s)) \neq \mathcal{R}_3(f(s'))$ and therefore $s$ and $s'$ must be coloured differently. This proves that $C$ is a proper colouring.

Notice that there is a general underlying argument: For $l$-ary strings you could prove that they can be coloured using $l$ colours in the very same way.